# Accessing parent DOM/function from within an Iframe embedded in Windows 7 gadget

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, parent, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have the following issue, Im creating a windows 7 gadget, which uses Iframe to load content.I have full control on the contents of the Iframe, what I want to do is, call a function in the parent (windows 7 gadget html document), from within this Iframe, or even trigger a flyout from within the Iframe, when there is hover on a link or something.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Windows Desktop Gadgets were initially said to be excluded from the restrictions of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), that is only true of XMLHttpRequests.  If the `<iframe>` is pointing to a page on the www, then any communication between the framed page and the hosting gadget will be blocked.  If this is the case then you *might* be able to use the method of cross-domain communication that relies on changing the `hash` of the topmost window.  From inside the frame, you would do something like this:

```
window.top.location.hash = "#ShowFlyout";
```

Then, in the code for the gadget you'd have something like this:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    if (window.location.hash == "#ShowFlyout") {
        window.location.hash = "";

        System.Gadget.Flyout.file = "flyout.htm";
        System.Gadget.Flyout.show = true;
    }
}, 100);
```

I don't have my windows machine on hand to test it right now, but you could try it nonetheless.

If the iframe is pointing to a html document on the local machine, then you should be able to access the global `System` variable as a member of the topmost window object — which is the gadget — like this:

```
var System = window.top.System;
System.Gadget.Flyout.file = "some.htm";
System.Gadget.Flyout.show = true;
```

Or, also assuming you have control over the content of the flyout, you could set an event handler on all links with jQuery (since you tagged it):

```
$("a", iframe.contentWindow.document).click(function () {
    System.Gadget.Flyout.file = this.href;
    System.Gadget.Flyout.show = true;
});
```

Comment: can the reverse be done on the same.Something like, using an event listener for links which are inside the iframe, and triggering a method on some user interaction within the links in this iframe?

Comment: there seems to be some issue, I tried doing the following :$("a", iframe.contentWindow).click(function () {
    $(this).css("background","red");
});
nothing seems to happen to anything in the iframe.I also tried $("a", document.getElementById("InoutIframe").contentWindow).live("mouseover",function () {
     $(this).css("background","red");     
    });, where the id of the iframe is InoutIframe, same results as before.Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Neeraj: my fault, it should be `.contentWindow.document`.

Comment: it seems there is some issue with cross origin policy somewhere... still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: to be more precise, when i try doing window.location="something.html" and window.top.location="something.html" then a new IE window opens and the new url is loaded there, a direct call to System.Gadget fails.

Comment: trying to access any part of parent.something gives a permission denied error.

Comment: @Neeraj: that was explained in the first part of my answer.  Where is the content in the iframe - on the internet, network or local machine?

Comment: its on a server hosted on local machine,  accessed using the local server url for the page.

Comment: @Neeraj: yeah, that violates the same origin policy for iframes, because you're accessing across different protocols (x-gadget vs http).  You might be able to use the `top.location.hash` hack (see my updated answer), but I'm not sure if it will work in a gadget and I don't have my Windows machine for testing at the moment.

Comment: @andy : tried the top.location.hash yesterday. :) doesnt work.The reason being stated in my last but one comment. the window.top and the top object point to another window, which actually opens up in IE :).seems like with each step , im speeding towards a big strong  wall :).